# How do i map group to set of groups, and then filter by one of them?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I love idea of LDAP, however i find it hard to use (at least as long as i'm a newbie in it). This is the reason why i kindly ask for your help, dear fellows.

I'm on phase of designing my directory, and what i'd like to do is:

- Add persons to abstract groups (developer, content producer, manager)
- Fill abstract groups with concrete groups (task manager access, scm access, server X shell)
- Let users be part of many abstract groups at once (programmer can be manager as well)
- Filter login queries by concrete group members (i.e. to access shell you have to be a programmer or administrator)

Any solution will be helpful. Of course i prefer common and/or standard ways of making this kidn of structure (so applications i use might recognize and display i.e. group pages).